# First backslash disappears when using autocomplete

Tags: sublime-text

After I updated my Sublime, the first backslash will disappear when I use autocomplete. For example, if I type "\begin" and press "Enter", it will become

> begin{}
> \end{}

How should I fix this problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it isn't related to TeX, LaTeX, and friends directly. Instead, it would appear a bug report about a program (sublime) that's linked only indirectly to LaTeX and Co. If this interpretation is correct, your query might be off-topic for this site and should be directed at the makers of sublime instead.

Comment: Nonetheless here is the hot-fix: https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/issues/1506#issuecomment-775060589 and the issue is also resolved in the ST 4 beta release (but Package Control won't install by default): https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/tags

Comment: @MauriceSchleußinger Thanks a lot! All this time I had been typing everything manually haha